# Данные из POST запроса не передаются при редиректе

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, post

Существует два роута для одной функции. Первый - для принятия POST запроса, второй - для возвращения view:

```
Route::post('polyclinics/get-doctor', [\App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController::class, 'index']); 
Route::resource('appointments', \App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController::class);
```

Метод контроллера AppointmentController, который получает запрос и возвращает view с данными из запроса:

```
class AppointmentController extends Controller
{
    protected $appointment = null;

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $this->appointment = $request->all();
        $data = json_encode($this->appointment);
        return view('appointments.index', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

И jQuery с отправкой запроса на роут:

```
$.post('get-doctor', {
    date: date,
    doctor: doctor,            
    time: time,
    _token: token
    }).done(function (response){
        console.log(response);
});
```

Данные без проблем отправляются по адресу и в качестве ответа без редиректа возвращается view с полученными данными, **НО** если делать редирект на appointments.index, то на странице данных из POST запроса нет

```
<a class="btn btn-info"value="{{ $time }}" href="{{ route('appointments.index') }}">{{ $time }}</a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если не делать редирект, то в качестве ответа возвращается view с полученными данными
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<a class="btn btn-info"value="{{ $time }}" href="#">{{ $time }}</a>
```

В чём может быть проблема и как совершить редирект на страницу с полученными из запроса данными?

Comment: POST-данные никогда не передавались и не будут передаваться через редирект.

Comment: @u_mulder а как тогда можно передать данные из запроса на другой роут?

Comment: А почему нельзя их сразу передать на нужный роут?

Comment: @u_mulder дело в том, что js-файле, перед тем как отправлять запрос, данные со страницы выбираются в соответствии с тем, какая кнопка была нажата  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1527172/jquery-Проблема-с-выводом-данных-из-html-кода-через-массив

Comment: И как это мешает отправлять данные сразу на нужный роут?

Comment: А как данные, собранные в js-коде, можно передать на нужный роут?

Comment: В смысле? Вот же запрос у тебя `$.post('get-doctor', {...`

Comment: Так проблема как раз таки и состоит в том, чтобы по этому роуту данные запроса вставлялись в представление и при переходе по роуту отображались

Comment: Используйте БД, сохраняйте выбранного доктора для записи, и при заходе на index выводите.

Comment: А если у доктора еще будет медсестра, которую тоже надо будет выводить, то ты сначала редиректнешься на доктора, оттуда на медсестру и только потом на нужный роут?

Comment: @u_mulder Вопрос состоял в передаче данных (как теперь выяснилось - в сохранении данных в бд и получении их на следующей странице). В моём же случае медсестёр нет, а происходит поэтапная передача данных для заказа талонов

Comment: @XenoProxy если база данных выглядит излишне -- используйте query params, они всегда передадутся.